# Tell me what's wrong with this code

Tags: verilog, modelsim

This code describes this expression -> `(a+b)(c+d)`. I used 2 summators, to first sum a and b, and then c and d. And then another one to multiply results. Unfortunately, I'm really bad at Verilog, so I'm unable to understand what's wrong.

```
  module automate(a,b,c,d,clk,start,result,ready);
  parameter n=8;
  input [7:0] a,b,c,d;
  input start,clk;
  output reg[17:0] result;
  output reg ready;
  reg[7:0] ra;
  reg[7:0] rb;
  reg[7:0] rc;
  reg[7:0] rd;
  reg[8:0] sm1;
  reg[8:0] sm2;
  reg[8:0] acc,q;

  always@(posedge start)
  begin
    ra=a;
    rb=b;
    rc=c;
    rd=d;

    sm1=ra+rb;
    sm2=rc+rd;

    q=sm2;
    acc=0;
    ready=0;

    repeat(9)
    begin
      @(posedge clk)
      if(q[0])
        acc=acc+sm1;
      else
        acc=acc;
      q=q>>1;
      q[8] = acc[0];
      acc=acc>>1;
    end

    ready=1;
    result={acc[8:0],q};
  end

endmodule
```

Testbench :

```
module test_bench;
reg[7:0] a,b,c,d;
reg clk,start;
wire ready;
wire[17:0] result;

automate res(a,b,c,d,clk,start,result,ready);
initial begin
  start = 0;
  clk=0;

  a=8'd7;
  b=8'd5;
  c=8'd9;
  d=8'd3;

  #30 start = 1;
  wait(ready);
  #20 start = 0;

  #500 $finish;
end

always #10 clk=~clk;

endmodule
```

but here's what I get:

[image]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1w6qbrmrj22f4gs/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: My guess is that you are simulating the module automate, not the testbench.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, you are right, I'm simulating the module automate... is it wrong? I get an error when I add to wave testbench -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/1w6qbrmrj22f4gs/Untitled.png?dl=0 . Could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Your testbench is called test_bench. That is the top level of your hierarchy, so you should simulate that. The module `automate` is instantiated in the test_bench and so is part of your hierarchy and so will be included. If you simulate the module `automate` then your testbench is not included and so the inputs to the module `automate` will not be driven.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine as per @Matthew Taylor!!,

Simulation is might not be of TB, as it is top module, ***nothing is driven to DUT*** so your signals are `X` and `Z`.

```
 .....
 automate res(a,b,c,d,clk,start,result,ready);
 initial begin
   $monitor (result, res.sm1, res.sm2); // added monitor system task
   start = 0;
 .....
```

And just run it, you will see then output as below,

```
#      x  x  x
#      x 12 12
#    144 12 12
```

Even though, I would like to say, you are writing HDL code, a real Hardware so don't use `repeat`, use ***for*** loop.

And if your requirement is just `(A+B) / (C+D)` then there is no use of clock.

For addition,

```
  always@(*)
  begin
    ra = 0;
    rb = 0;
    rc = 0;
    sm1 = 0;
    sm2 = 0;
    result = 0;

    if(start) begin
      ra = a;
      rb = b;
      rc = c;
      rd = d;

      sm1 = ra + rb;
      sm2 = rc + rd;

      result = product(sm1, sm2);
    end
  end
```

For function `product` which will multiply `sm1` and `sm2` can be,

```
  function [17:0] product;
    input [8:0]  multiplier, multiplicand;

    integer i;

    begin
      product = 0;
      for(i=0; i<17; i=i+1)
        if( multiplier[i] == 1'b1 )
          product = product + ( multiplicand << i );
     end
   endfunction
```

So I think start and ready would be asserted on same cycle. No sequential logic is there in your code, as of now.

Hope this will help you.

Edit:

for your second problem, use following transcript commands:

```
vsim -novopt -c -do "add wave -r /*; run -all;" work.test_bench

add wave -r /*

run -all
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry, but could you explain what does " nothing is driven to DUT" mean?

Comment: if you dont run testbench, the inputs connected to your design modue is not driven and remains unconnected so results into "nothing is driven to DUT(design under test)"

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works!!! After writing transcript commands it started to work!!